# Change image color in svg element

Tags: html, css, image, svg, mask

The goal is to show image but with another color inside svg.
I tried  -webkit-mask-image with background-color, but this combination does not work in svg. Here is the example:

```
<div class="dashboard-buttons">
  <svg  width="367" height="243.5" viewBox="252.5 60.5 367 243.5">
    <g>
      <rect width="46" height="46" rx="4" ry="4" transform="translate(-23, -23)" style="fill:white" x="560" y="224"></rect>
      <a xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#element3" href="#element3" onclick="window.location.href = '#element3';">
        <image height="32" width="32" transform="translate(-16, -16)" x="560" y="224" style="background-color: Red; -webkit-mask-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAACxIAAAsSAdLdfvwAAAAYdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHBhaW50Lm5ldCA0LjAuM4zml1AAAACqSURBVFhH7ZYhDsJAFESHBMkBOCYGyQV6BQ6BQ0EwWByiuwj0Fk5AgO00+XJpCd20gpnkqfZnXrJmoCiVx+rmcWyD/2zCGXM7yZvK4c2S2InDiRIzO8uXZNkHgsM2HjC10zxJFXWwjsDEzvsnUfANVz7JpS93j+JXgSyEEs9RBRokIAEJSEACEpDA+AIcpa/UhyHg2n6A02jJabSjyH5Qms4SC1uGyt8GqAEZtGBDEZcerAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');width: 32px; height: 32px;"></image>
      </a>

      <a xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#element3"><text filter="url(#fillbackground)" x="560" y="257">out</text></a>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

If you remove svg tags from it then this sample works and the color changed.

Do you know how to change image color inside svg correctly?

EDIT:

The following code works in Chrome, but not in Firefox:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <svg width="200" height="300" class="svg">
        <defs>  
   <mask id="mask">
        <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAACxIAAAsSAdLdfvwAAAAYdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHBhaW50Lm5ldCA0LjAuM4zml1AAAACqSURBVFhH7ZYhDsJAFESHBMkBOCYGyQV6BQ6BQ0EwWByiuwj0Fk5AgO00+XJpCd20gpnkqfZnXrJmoCiVx+rmcWyD/2zCGXM7yZvK4c2S2InDiRIzO8uXZNkHgsM2HjC10zxJFXWwjsDEzvsnUfANVz7JpS93j+JXgSyEEs9RBRokIAEJSEACEpDA+AIcpa/UhyHg2n6A02jJabSjyH5Qms4SC1uGyt8GqAEZtGBDEZcerAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
  </image>
        </mask>
 </defs>

              <rect width="50" height="50" style="fill:blue;" x="0" y="0" 
mask="url(#mask)"></rect>

    </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It doesn't work in Firefox because the image element in the second example has no width and height attributes.

Answer (score -1):

Can't see your example, but:

```html
<rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100" stroke="blue" fill="purple"
       fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-opacity="0.8"/>
```

Use the **fill** option!

EDIT:
Now I can see your code.
If you insert an image as PNG:

> data:image/png

Then I doubt you can change the color with HTML directive. PNG are bitmaps and not SVG, you would have to edit the PNG itself to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does it mean that if I replace this png with svg encoded image then the sample must work?

Comment: I tried 
data:image/svg+xml;base64,... image
 and it does not help